# i have defined this structure but when i compile the code i get the following error - declaration is incompatible with "Fileheader *pFileheader"

Tags: c

```
typedef struct tagFileheader    
{
    unsigned short   Type;                  //  00h  File Type Identifier  
    unsigned int     FileSize;              //  02h  Size of bmp file          
    unsigned int     PxOffset;              //  0Ah  Offset to bitmap pixel   
}Fileheader;

Fileheader *pFileheader;
pFileheader = &Fileheader;
```

Comment: Remove the typedef, If I got your intention right.

Answer (score 2):

`Fileheader` is a type. So `&Fileheader` doesn't mean anything. The addressof operator `&` operates on instances. You need an existing object:

```
typedef struct tagFileheader {} Fileheader;

int main(void)
{
    Fileheader fhdr;
    Fileheader *pFileheader;
    ....
    pFileheader = &fhdr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have done what u said..but now i get this   :error - pFileheader = &fhdr; this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Comment: @tapanchawda That should work. I extended the example to make it complete.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol `Fileheader` is a *type*, and as such doesn't doesn't really exists anywhere in memory during run-time. Therefore you can't take the address of it.

You can take the address of other variables, like e.g.

```
Fileheader myFileheader;
Fileheader *pFileheader = &myFileheader;
```

Or allocate dynamically during run-time, like

```
Fileheader *pFileheader = malloc(sizeof(Fileheader));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Fileheader *pFileheader;
```

Fileheader is the new type which you have created by making use of typedef so you can't have a type being assigned to the pointer.

```
pFileheader = &Fileheader;
```

I hope this is want you wanted. Make you pointer point to some valid memory location.

```
int main()
{
   Fileheader *pFileheader = malloc(sizeof(struct tagFileHeader));
}
```

Comment: yea...i did it..thank you...its working..i will remember this